# Glassfish TimerService: Exception in TimerHandle Deserialization when updating vom GF 3.1 to 4.1

Tags: java, glassfish

I'm updating a Java EE 6 application from GF 3.1.2.2 to 4.1. The application heavily uses the EJB timer services and persists `TimerHandle` objects in the DB.

I get the following exception when accessing those timer handles in the DB:

```
Exception [EclipseLink-66] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Could not deserialize object from byte array.
Internal Exception: java.io.InvalidClassException: com.sun.ejb.containers.TimerWrapper$TimerHandleImpl; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 8013326429831986199, local class serialVersionUID = -7638766191514989908
Mapping: org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DirectToFieldMapping[timerHandle-->MESSAGE.TIMERHANDLE]
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.example.Message --> [DatabaseTable(MESSAGE)])
```

Apparently, serial version IDs have changed from GF 3.1 to 4.1. Any ideas how to reuse those TimerHandle objects in GF 4.1.